# UK horror movie involving a team of University students studying and documenting a possessed girl they keep locked in room

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I believe this horror movie was based in the UK. The movie began on a University campus. A team of university students and their professor take this possessed girl to an isolated house in the country side to study and document her possession.

Some key things I remember about the movie is that they keep the possessed girl locked in her room and constantly play loud music through the speakers in her room. I believe the guy filming the study begins to fall in love with the possessed girl but the movie ends with everyone dying.

I think the movie was also based on a true story, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made?

Answer (score 6):

Could this be [*The Quiet Ones*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2235779/) (2014)?

> A university professor and a team of students conduct an experiment on
> a young woman, uncovering terrifyingly dark, unexpected forces in the
> process.

Allegedly inspired by "*actual events*"